# Get parent directory of running script

Tags: php, directory

In PHP, what would be the cleanest way to get the **parent** directory of the current running script relative to the www root? Assume I have:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/relative/path/to/script/index.php'
```

Or just:

```
$something_else == '/relative/path/to/script/'
```

And I need to get `/relative/path/to/` with slashes properly inserted. What would you suggest? A one liner is preferred.

**EDIT**

I need to get a path relative to the www root, `dirname(__FILE__)` gives me an absolute path in the filesystem so that won't work. `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` on the other hand 'starts' at the www root.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If your script is located in `/var/www/dir/index.php` then the following would return:

```
dirname(__FILE__); // /var/www/dir
```

or

```
dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ); // /var/www
```

---

#### Edit

This is a technique used in many frameworks to determine relative paths from the app_root.

File structure:

```
 /var/
      www/
          index.php
          subdir/
                 library.php
```

index.php is my dispatcher/boostrap file that all requests are routed to:

```
define(ROOT_PATH, dirname(__FILE__) ); // /var/www
```

library.php is some file located an extra directory down and I need to determine the path relative to the app root (/var/www/).

```
$path_current = dirname( __FILE__ ); // /var/www/subdir
$path_relative = str_replace(ROOT_PATH, '', $path_current); // /subdir
```

There's probably a better way to calculate the relative path then `str_replace()` but you get the idea.

Comment: That won't work as I need the path relative to the www root. I could just replace the /var/www part out of it, but this needs to work on Windows and *nix.

Comment: There is no dependable sure-fire way of determining the ROOT_PATH on all OS's on all servers. The best practice technique is to `define(ROOT_PATH, dirname(__FILE__));` early in your stack (hopefully you use a common dispatcher or bootstrap so this won't be a headache to implement) and use that in conjunction with other functions to produce a relative path.

Comment: In my case it's the other way down. All requests are routed to /something/cms/index.php so setting ROOT_PATH from there results in /something/cms/, and I need to access the parent directory /something/. So I guess I'll just have to resort to some ugly string manipulation.

Comment: I've been using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` to get the directory, but I like this idea. Excellent answer.

Comment: As of PHP 7.0.0, `dirname(__FILE__, 2)` can be used instead of `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))`.
[`dirname` Changelog](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php#refsect1-function.dirname-changelog)

Answer (score 15):

As of PHP 5.3.0 you can use `__DIR__` for this purpose.

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   dirname(__ FILE__).

See [PHP Magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

```
C:\www>php --version
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2013 11:33:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

C:\www>php -r "echo __DIR__;"
C:\www
```

Answer (score 13):

To get the parentdir of the current script.

```
$parent_dir = dirname(__DIR__);
```

Answer (score 8):

If I properly understood your question, supposing your running script is

```
/relative/path/to/script/index.php
```

This would give you the parent directory of your running script relative to the document www:

```
$parent_dir = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
//$parent_dir will be '/relative/path/to/'
```

If you want the parent directory of your running script relative to server root:

```
$parent_dir = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) . '/';
//$parent_dir will be '/root/some/path/relative/path/to/'
```

Comment: Hi!

I've tried to ask this before... Is it common practice to put a trailing slash or omit it? I like to omit it because:
`$url = BASE_URL . '/my/path/';`
looks better to me than `$url = BASE_URL . 'my/path/';`. Is there a standard way or what's most common?

Comment: @nbrogi: I like to always add it, so you can immediately see it's a directory/folder and not a file name without the extension.

Answer (score 7):

I Hope this will help you.

```
echo getcwd().'<br>'; // getcwd() will return current working directory
echo dirname(getcwd(),1).'<br>';
echo dirname(getcwd(),2).'<br>';
echo dirname(getcwd(),3).'<br>';
```

Output :

```
C:\wamp64\www\public_html\step
C:\wamp64\www\public_html
C:\wamp64\www
C:\wamp64
```

Answer (score 5):

Fugly, but this will do it:

```
substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$dir = dirname($file) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: But isn't a `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR define` a needless thing? PHP seems to work well with both type of slashes `/ \\` also on Windows machines.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use since I am not running > 5.2

```
function getCurrentOrParentDirectory($type='current')
{
    if ($type == 'current') {
        $path = dirname(__FILE__);  
    } else {
        $path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
    }
    $position = strrpos($path, '/') + 1;
    return substr($path, $position);
}
```

Double dirname with file as suggested by @mike b for the parent directory, and current directory is found by just using that syntax once.

***Note this function only returns the NAME, slashes have to be added afterwards.***

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that I use. Created it once so I always have this functionality:

```
function getDir(){
    $directory = dirname(__FILE__);
    $directory = explode("/",$directory);
    $findTarget = 0;
    $targetPath = "";
    foreach($directory as $dir){
        if($findTarget == 1){
            $targetPath = "".$targetPath."/".$dir."";
        }
        if($dir == "public_html"){
            $findTarget = 1;
        }
    }
    return "http://www.".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."".$targetPath."";
}
```

Comment: If I understand well this script seeks the absolute path to "public_html". In this case, shouldn't the ' == ' symbol be replaced by ' != ' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. **Works on both windows or linux server..**

str_replace('\\','/',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))

Answer (score 0):

This is also a possible solution

```
$relative = '/relative/path/to/script/';
$absolute = __DIR__. '/../' .$relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```
function get_directory(){
    $s = empty($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? '' : ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "s" : "";
    $protocol = substr(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), 0, strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]), "/")) . $s;
    $port = ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "80") ? "" : (":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]);
return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
define("ROOT_PATH", get_directory()."/" );
echo ROOT_PATH;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parentDirOfParent = dirname(__DIR__, 2);
```

if you want to get 2 level before use dirname just once with argument 2

Answer (score -7):

Got it myself, it's a bit kludgy but it works:

```
substr(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, strrpos(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/') + 1)
```

So if I have `/path/to/folder/index.php`, this results in `/path/to/`.

Comment: I don't understand you simply need to call twice `dirname` in order to reach the parent directory, see my answer.