# PHP - Getting a current directory

Tags: php

I'll set the scene...

1. I've got a file **example.php**
2. That particular file is in a folder called **test**
3. The full file path is /root/user/website/htdocs/test/example.php

What I'd like is to echo the directory the file is in ie. **test**

I've managed to do this by reading the functions and creating the script below, is this a bad way of going about this? is there an easier way?

```
<?php
$dir_array = explode('/', getcwd());
$dir_current = end($dir_array);

echo $dir_current;
?>
```

outputs `test`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882044/get-parent-directory-of-running-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a constant for this:

```
echo __DIR__;
```

if you just want to have the last part of the path - `test` - in your case, then use [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
echo basename(__DIR__);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, it does the same job but a bit cleaner. Many Thanks. `<?php
echo basename(__DIR__);
?>`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you the following code:

```
echo array_pop(explode('/', dirname(__FILE__)));
```

If your PHP version is above 5.3.0, you can replace `dirname(__FILE__)` with `__DIR__`

For the problems with `getcwd()` you can read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 0):

Considering this path `store.com/products/electronics/index.php`

This also works with `include()`

The 3rd combination should work for the OP.

---

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

/products/electronics/index.php

---

```
dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

/products/electronics

---

```
basename(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

electronics

---

```
basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

index.php

---

Answer (score -1):

Almost:

```
<?php
$dir_current = $dir_array[count($dir_array)-1];
?>
```