# How to add parent dir variable to scandir (PHP)

Tags: php

Hi sorry this is probably a really newbie question, but I'm searching for the answer for 2 days now and no luck.
I'm using a script what generates an image gallery from an uploaded folder.
Script info:
Tim-thumb script created by Tim McDaniels and Darren Hoyt with tweaks by Ben Gillbanks.

You need to add the directory name what contains the images to the script like:

```
 $dirname = "images/"  ;
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    shuffle($images);
```

What I'm trying to do is make the script work automatically if i upload it in a new folder with new images so I don't need to add the $dirname every time I upload a gallery.
for example:

**$dirname = $mydir  ;**

where mydir returns the path of the current directory like:

**$mydir = basename(getcwd()) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;**

but it's not working.

also tried to make it work from a function:

```
function current_dir()
{$path = dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]);$position = strrpos($path,'/') + 1;print substr($path,$position);}
```

than -->

**$dirname = current_dir()  ;**

but no luck.
I think I'm missing something here, I'm a totally noob and maybe it's just a syntax issue but can't make it work.
I always get 
[function.scandir]: failed to open dir ...
or creates the gallery but the images not working (I see only alt tags)
thank you for any help.

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

**EDIT :
!!!**

Just realized... :o !!!
**The answer is:**

```
$dirname = "./"  ;
```

omg

**<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<**

"I think I'm missing something here..."
:D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parent directory of running script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882044/get-parent-directory-of-running-script)

Comment: yes but the problem is, I dont get the images, only the alt tags show up this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$parent = dirname(__DIR__);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Thank you, but just like above, I dont get the images, only the alt tags show up this way.

Comment: Can you see image buy typing URL in browser? If not check folder privileges

Comment: Yes, thanks again for the help, i found a solution.But if I use what I asked here, than the gallery contains all files in the directory, and I need only the images.so I changed the directory structure.It works now, just not how I wanted first.Have a great day, thanks again. @sasa